# What is the theoretically maximum value of nf_conntrack_count?

Tags: netfilter

I have a Linux server with DNAT enabled, and it suffers from packet loss, aka `nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`.

Now I need to increase conntrack memory usage by updating the `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` value.

1. If the system is IPv4 only, what is the theoretical maximum number of connections that need to be tracked?
2. Given the maximum number of connections to track, how do I calculate the amount of kernel memory needed?